# In quantum mechanics, do quantum systems not exist before measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

If a quantum system manifests itself only during measurement, and if the wave function is only our knowledge of a quantum system, maybe it does not physically exist at all before measurement? Maybe a quantum system is something that appears in reality only during measurement, and before that it does not exist at all?

Comment: This is not specific to quantum mechanics. I also think it's philosophy, not physics.

Comment: It is like saying Jupiter does not exist unless someone sees Jupiter or measure its effects. I don't know how to disapprove it or it can disapproved at all. But that is not really something which we talk about.

Comment: This is not entirely off-topic, and not entirely wrong, as the Copenhagen Interpretation is "mainstream physics". Someone could post an answer clarifying the distinction between physics and philosophy, the measurement problem, and the interpretations of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @electronpusher Interestingly, does the Copenhagen interpretation exclude the existence of a quantum state before measurement, or does it say that it is indefinable?

Comment: *does the Copenhagen interpretation exclude the existence of a quantum state before measurement, or does it say that it is indefinable?*  No and no.

Comment: @WillO Then what does the Copenhagen interpretation say?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress :  Probably no two people will agree on the details of what is meant by "Copenhagen interpretation", but roughly it means that the state of a quantum system evolves unitarily until the time of a measurement, at which point it jumps discontinuously into an eigenstate of that measurement, chosen probabilistically according to the Born rule.

Comment: @WillO Does this state really exist before measurement, or is it just a mathematical description?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress :  What is the difference between "exist" and "really exist"?

Comment: @WillO It's about whether a quantum state exists before measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever a measurement is, the quantum system always exists, otherwise what's qm all about? It may not have well defined values for some of its properties, but that's different and only says that a quantum system is different than a classical one. Now, some people would say that qm is about the values we measure and the regularities that they display. But that begs the question, why the regularities? Answer: because there's something there, that exists and has its character! These people can insist and say that only the regularities exist. Fair enough, but  something has to exist then, name it as you want, it's the same thing. Personally, I prefer the system-exists view, since the empirist/operational view invokes things like observers, etc., which don't have a correlate in the mathematical formalism, they are superfluous. What  models the observer and its details in a spin matrix? Nothing, it only depends and only tells you things about the system alone.